# Postgres transaction blocks: when does locking begin?

Tags: postgresql

In Postgres 9.4, if I wrap commits inside a transaction, by typing:

```
BEGIN;
UPDATE mytable(email)...
COMMIT;
```

I understand it will lock the tables used in the transaction, for the duration of the transaction.

But when does the locking actually start? Does it start when I press Enter after `COMMIT`? Or does it start when I press Enter after `BEGIN`?

And if there's only one commit in the transaction, is the locking behaviour any different in nature from just typing the commit directly?

Comment: An `update` will not lock "the table" - it only locks the _rows_ that are affected by the update statement. The lock is obtained when the `UPDATE` is executed. Neither begin nor commit will lock anything. In fact `commit` will **release** all locks that were made during the transaction

Comment: one transaction can have many locking statements, eg 'lock table a; lock table b;` each will be locked on the statement - transaction can't forsee what relation or tuple you want to lock and how, thus nothing is locked on begin. and on commit - it is too late to lock anything.

Comment: An `UPDATE` locks the table in `ROW EXCLUSIVE` mode. Apart from that I concur with @a_horse_with_no_name.